# Entity core Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint error when update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper

There is typical many to many relationship between books and authors.
I've got an error when I tried to update my authors. The full name of error is "SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_BookAuthor'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BookAuthor'. The duplicate key value is (2, 2)."

If I don't use UpdateAssociatedObject function, all is okay. But if I use it, I get the error when I try to save the changes.

```
 var parseBook = Mapper.Map<BookViewModel, Book>(viewModel);
        Book viewModelBook = parseBook;
        var book = db.Books.FindOne(viewModel.BookId);
        book.BookId = viewModelBook.BookId;
        book.BookName = viewModelBook.BookName;
        book.Genre = viewModelBook.Genre;
        book.Pages = viewModelBook.Pages;
        book.Publisher = viewModelBook.Publisher;
        db.SaveChanges();
        UpdateAssociatedObject(book, viewModelBook);
    }
    public void UpdateAssociatedObject(Book bookForUpdate, Book book)
    {
        bookForUpdate.BookAuthors = book.BookAuthors;
    //error is here
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**The value of viewModelBook after mapping:**
[image: The value of BookAuthor property]
**Models(some properties removed for brevity)**

```
 public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public List<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
}
public class Author
    {
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public List<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
    }
 public class BookAuthor
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
public class BookViewModel
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<AuthorViewModel> Authors { get; set; }    
}
public class AuthorViewModel
    {
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }

        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    }
public class Library : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BookAuthor>().HasKey(sc => new { sc.BookId, sc.AuthorId });
    }
}
```

**Mapper:**

```
 CreateMap<BookViewModel, Book>()
            .ForMember(b => b.BookId, opt => opt.MapFrom(b => b.BookId))
        .PreserveReferences()
        .ForMember(b => b.BookAuthors, opt => opt.MapFrom(b => b.Authors
        .Select(a => new BookAuthor { AuthorId = a.AuthorId })));
```

**UPD:** BookId jumps after creating a book(in steps of 1000).

After adding Include() to Find method, the error changed on

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'BookAuthor' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'BookId', 'AuthorId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'

Comment: I've had a similar problem, but in relationships 1 to n.
At the beginning of the UpdateAssociatedObject function, is the bookForUpdate.BookAuthors object null?
If it is not null, you can try to use the methods of the collection (eg Add)

Comment: @Gustavo Rossi Muller sorry for delay, unfortunately  bookForUpdate.BookAuthors object is null.

Comment: Even if it's not null, the error is the same(

Comment: I do not know much about AutoMapper, but I think the following is happening:
You have a list of authors, some new, others removed, and others updated.
I think the updated authors are generating the problem.
The EF uses an object as a proxy to refer to the records in the base, if it is a normal object it will try to give insert, even if the PK already exists.
Can you check the type of object that is on your list (using watch)? Maybe it's an EF class that inherits from Author, in that case I'm talking nonsense.

Comment: The type is Author or somethingPROXYsomethingAuthor?

Comment: The type of bookAuthors is {LibraryAngularApp.DAL.Entities.JoinTables.BookAuthor}.
Type of authors I can't check because it is still null.

Comment: I think that's why you're creating the record again.
Unfortunately, I do not know much about AutoMapper.
As a workarround, you could delete the old records and insert the new ones, and only then call the SaveChanges.

Comment: I thought about it but BookAuthors is null, how can I do any operations with it? I thought also about to add Include() to my Find method however I think it's not the best idea.

Comment: try include a DBSet in the context, and use they to retrieve.

Comment: It was a good idea, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it works! Below you can see the differences from original code.

P.S Perhaps you know better algorithm for Remove method, if so you can type it in comments then I will change the answer.

**BookRepository:**

```
 public Book Find(int id)
    {
        Book searchedBook = db.Books
          .Include(b => b.BookAuthors)
          .ThenInclude(b => b.Author)
          .SingleOrDefault(b => b.BookId == id);

        return searchedBook;
    }
```

**BookService:**

```
public void UpdateObject(BookViewModel viewModel)
        {
            Book parsedBook = Mapper.Map<BookViewModel, Book>(viewModel);
            //Book viewModelBook = parseBook;
            var book = db.Books.Find(viewModel.BookId);
            book.BookId = parsedBook.BookId;
            book.BookName = parsedBook.BookName;
            book.Genre = parsedBook.Genre;
            book.Pages = parsedBook.Pages;
            book.Publisher = parsedBook.Publisher;
            UpdateAssociatedObject(book, parsedBook);
        }
public void UpdateAssociatedObject(Book bookToUpdate, Book viewModelBook)
        {
            AddUpdatedAuthors(bookToUpdate, viewModelBook);
            RemoveUpdatedAuthors(bookToUpdate, viewModelBook);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
     private void AddUpdatedAuthors(Book bookToUpdate, Book viewModelBook)
        {
            foreach (var authors in viewModelBook.BookAuthors)
            {
                var searchBookAuthor = bookToUpdate.BookAuthors.Find(b => b.AuthorId == authors.AuthorId);
                if (searchBookAuthor == null)
                {
                    bookToUpdate.BookAuthors.Add(authors);
                }
            }
        }
        private void RemoveUpdatedAuthors(Book bookToUpdate, Book viewModelBook)
        {
            int countOfAuthors = bookToUpdate.BookAuthors.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < countOfAuthors; i++)
            {
                BookAuthor searchBookAuthor = null;
                foreach (var viewModelAuthors in viewModelBook.BookAuthors)
                {
                    if (viewModelAuthors.AuthorId == bookToUpdate.BookAuthors[i].AuthorId)
                    {
                        searchBookAuthor = viewModelAuthors;
                    }
                }
                if (searchBookAuthor == null)
                {
                    bookToUpdate.BookAuthors.Remove(bookToUpdate.BookAuthors[i]);
                    i--;
                    countOfAuthors--;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks with db.SaveChanges(). You are calling db.SaveChanges with same context multiple times in

```
db.SaveChanges();

UpdateAssociatedObject(book, viewModelBook);
```

and in `UpdateAssociatedObject(book, viewModelBook);`
Try removing one db.SaveChanges().